# After signing the document dl.signhere.1 and dl.signhere.2 is not replace with signature instead it is overlapping these text

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am using drawloop to generate document after that I am using docusign as delivery method for sending documents for signature. In my template I am using  dl.signhere.1 and dl.signhere.2 but after signing process completed. After signing the document dl.signhere.1 and dl.signhere.2 is not replace with signature instead it is overlapping these text that doen't looks good.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're able to edit the template, change the font color of the text strings **dl.signhere.1** and **dl.signhere.2** such that it matches the background color of the document -- thereby rendering the text 'invisible'. i.e., if the document's background color is white, changing the font color of those strings to white will render them invisible in the document, but since that text still technically exists, DocuSign will be able to detect it to know where to place the signatures.